# How to make multiple hexagonal holes on inventor?

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-inventor

i'm trying to make the following pattern on inventor. is there a more efficient way of doing this other than drawing each hexagon and extruding it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is better forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-forum/bd-p/78) for questions for Inventor users, but here is my answer:

1. You can use multiple rectangular patterns

[image: First pattern]

[image: Second pattern]

[image: Third pattern]

[image: Result]

2. You can use single pattern and disable unwanted pattern occurrences

[image: Single pattern with two directions]

[image: Suppress pattern occurrences]